# jQuery draggable not working on windows 10 touchscreen desktop

Tags: jquery-ui

There is an issue with the draggable feature of the jQuery UI library. We have used the recommended solution of the touch punch library, but still, it does not support windows touch screen PCs or Laptops. It works for iPad, iPhones, Android phones and tablets etc.

We tried a solution:

## HTML

```
<div id="TrendsAreaTrends">
 <div class="graph-scrollbar">
    <div class="graph-scroll-container">
        <div class="graph-scroll"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

## Script

```
 $("#TrendsAreaTrends. graph-scroll").draggable({
         `   axis: "x", containment: "parent",`
            `drag: function (event, ui) {`
              `  if (vitalHelper.currentScrollX - ui.position.left > 30) {`
                    vitalHelper.handleMoved = true;
                }
                else {
                    vitalHelper.handleMoved = false;
                }
                shiftHorizontal(ui.position.left);
            }
        });
```

We used the following libraries:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.13.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

I tried the following links :

1. General overview - https://impossiblue.github.io/log/170425/index.html
2. About using touch punch - https://github.com/RWAP/jquery-ui-touch-punch
3. Specific solution- https://h5ptechnology.atlassian.net/browse/HFP-3063
4. Issues using touch punch in windows touch laptops: https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/issues/331

We tested with other devices, the solution seems to work, but doesn't respond in the windows touch laptop on any browser - chrome, edge, IE.

These URLs suggested that there was an issue with the draggable feature of jQuery UI, which has been fixed with a touch punch patch. But in our case, we are already using a touch punch patch, but it still needs to solve our problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This will be difficult to troubleshoot and reproduce as many may not have access to that specific device. You may need to do some testing on the device to see what events are being triggered, `click` versus `touch`. I would assume that the touch screen is passing tap and touch events but I could be wrong, it might be translating them into mouse click events in the OS. Therefore, you want to test in your scripts to see what is coming through. Do you see any Console errors?

Comment: Hi @Twisty, I found no console errors with the touch-punch library, but when I incorporated the RWAP( https://github.com/RWAP/jquery-ui-touch-punch), I got some errors - Ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart event with cancelable=false, for example, because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.